# onClick needs double click without jquery

Tags: javascript

I have 2 buttons at my page and i want to change their content after the user clicks with onclick.But it works only after the second click.After that it only needs only one click to change again.

```
<button class="event btn btn-primary btn-responsive" type="button" id =<%=eventId %> 
 onclick="myFunctionEvent(this.id,<%=user.getId()%>)">
  Join the Event
</button>
```

The javascript function

```
/*EVENT Button*/
 function myFunctionEvent(eventId,userId) {   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var checkId;
    var change = document.getElementById(eventId);  
    if (change.innerHTML == "Join the Event")
    {
       change.innerHTML = "I will be there";

       checkId = "1";

       /*xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=errorFunction()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                 var answer = xmlhttp.responseText;
                 alert(answer);
            }
        }   */   
    }
    else {
        change.innerHTML = "Join the Event";
        checkId = "2";  
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","updateNotif.jsp?event="+eventId+
                 "&user="+userId+"&checkId="+checkId,true
                );
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Why not `onclick="myFunctionEvent(this,<%=user.getId()%>)" >` - then do  `function myFunctionEvent(but,userId) {` and use `but.innerHTML=but.innerHTML=="Join the Event"?"I will be there":"Join the Event"`

Comment: You should never use string comparison to check the state of something. I can easily reproduce the problem by adding a space to the button's text.

Comment: Just about style. Why not do myFunctionEvent.call(this). Then you can use this inside of the function and dont need to search the object again

Comment: I think the reason this happens is because after you click the button, it must go to the server to find out what the parameter is that it needs to pass to the onclick function. myFunctionEvent(this.id,<%=user.getId()%>) and then 2nd click it can use that parameter. 1st click doesn't execute myFunctionEvents(), it only grabs user.getId().

Comment: @Chris G whatcan i do instead of string comparison'

Comment: You can use String comparison, but you need to compare against `'I will be there'`, and use `else` for the alternative. That way the button will definitely switch on the first click, even if the current `innerHTML` isn't exactly `'Join the Event'`. Here's my version: https://jsfiddle.net/ousoqfhw/2/

Comment: @Chris G  i get an error when i change the order of if-statements.Thanks for the code, but i dont understand where do  data-userid type exist in button

Comment: @maria They exist because HTML allows adding arbitrary attributes to elements. You can make up their names, but using `data-xyz` is a common pattern for naming them. It's a straightforward way of passing data from the backend to the frontend.

Comment: What can i use instead of arbitrary attributes? I dont think that they work because of  old HTML